# Eclipse WSDL errors in ws-security elements related to request_headers

Tags: eclipse, soap, wsdl, ws-security, request-headers

I have WSDL starting from

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"  
xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"  
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"  
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
```

For this WSDL Eclipse Kepler gives me 2 WSDL type errors:

Error 1:
The part 'request_headers' has an invalid value 'Security' defined for its element. Element declarations must refer to valid values defined in a schema.    etframework.wsdl    /smartdestinations-connect/src/main/java/com/smartdestinations/exacttarget/

This error is generated for the element:

```
<message name="Security">
    <part element="wsse:Security" name="request_headers" />
</message>
```

Error 2:

The 'request_header' part specified in message 'Security' for the SOAP header is undefined. Ensure the part is defined in the 'Security' message.

This error is generated for the element:

```
<binding name="SoapBinding" type="tns:Soap">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
...
<operation name="Retrieve">
  <soap:operation soapAction="Retrieve" />
  <input>
    <soap:header message="tns:Security" part="request_header" use="literal"/>
    <soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal" />
  </input>
  <output>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </output>
</operation>
```

…

How to remove these errors?